# FTP over SSL issue

Tags: c#, ssl, ftp

I'm having issue uploading file to ftp site over SSL to specific directory. I'm using `System.Net.FtpWebRequest` `class` for this purpose. Upload going through fine. But the file always dropped to home directory. Any idea what might be doing wrong? Appreciate your help.

```
    public bool UploadFile(string srcFilePath, string destFilePath = null)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(srcFilePath))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("Source FilePath.");

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destFilePath))
            destFilePath = Path.GetFileName(srcFilePath);

        Uri serverUri = GetUri(destFilePath);

        //// the serverUri should start with the ftp:// scheme.
        if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
            return false;

        // get the object used to communicate with the server.
        FtpWebRequest request = CreateFtpRequest(serverUri, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile);

        // read file into byte array
        StreamReader sourceStream = new StreamReader(srcFilePath);
        byte[] fileContents = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sourceStream.ReadToEnd());
        sourceStream.Close();
        request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;

        // send bytes to server
        Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Debug.WriteLine("Response status: {0} - {1}", response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);

        return true;
    }

    private FtpWebRequest CreateFtpRequest(Uri serverUri, string method)
    {
        FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
        request.EnableSsl = true;
        request.UsePassive = true;
        request.UseBinary = true;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_userName, _password);
        request.Method = method;
        return request;
    }

    private Uri GetUri(string remoteFilePath)
    {
        return new Uri(_baseUri, remoteFilePath);
    }
```

Comment: Without showing your code, it's unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: `Raj` when you debug this line here `Uri serverUri = GetUri(destFilePath);` what is the exact value of `serverUri` ??

Comment: The ftp path resolved into correct path. ie. ftp://ftp.xxxx.com/ch02/test.xml
But the file trasnferred into ftp://ftp.xxxx.com/text.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Finally figured it out. It is .NET 4.0 framework issue. Build the solution with .NET 3.5, it worked beautifully.

Hate to see bugs in new releases of .NET from Microsoft and wasting lot of quality time in figuring out.